# Find prev() tags with several selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors

Let's face this situation:

```
<ul>
  <li>data</li>
  <li class="selector">data2</li>
  <li class="selector2">data3</li>
</ul>
```

What i'm trying to do is match `li`s that either have `selector` class or have class attribute `undefined`, something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.selector2').prevAll('li.selector OR li[class==""]');
});
```

So if I'm running `prevAll()` on the `.selector2`, it should return 2 list items. If i run it on `.selector`, it should return the first list item.

So is there a way to replace that OR ... ?

*PS: xpath may work for me too as i'm developing for modern browsers*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.selector2').prevAll('li.selector, li:not([class])');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/189/)**

#### Adding in important comment from @pimvdb

> This is correct, but be careful - something like
>   `.addClass("foo").removeClass("foo")` leaves the class attribute
>   behind, although you (might) expect it to be in it's initial state. So
>   it's not quite the same as `[class='']`.

Comment: This is correct, but be careful - something like `.addClass("foo").removeClass("foo")` leaves the `class` attribute behind, although you (might) expect it to be in it's initial state. So it's not quite the same as `[class='']`.

Answer (score 4):

> What i'm trying to do is match `li`s that either have "selector" class
>   or have class attribute undefined

**This XPath expression is equivalent to the pseudo-code in the question**:

```
/ul/li[@class='selector2']/preceding-sibling::li[@class='selector' or not(@class)]
```

**However, a *literal* translation of the quoted requirement is**:

```
/ul/li[@class='selector' or not(@class)]
```